# Is there a similar concept of resource state decay or promotion in Vulkan?

Tags: vulkan

I had learned Direct3D 12 when I started to learn Vulkan. I remember that there is a concept about resource state decay or promotion in Direct3D 12. Is there a similar concept in Vulkan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vulkan doesn't really have an equivalent to the D3D12 concept of "resource state". The closest equivalent might be image layouts, but 1) those only apply to images, and 2) all layout transitions are explicitly specified by the user.

It seems to me that D3D12's "resource state" bundles together the question of the availability of the data within the resource. That is, if some commands wrote some data to that resource, the resource state partially dictates whether later commands can read that data. Within the same command list, you would need an explicit resource state barrier, but if there is a point where resources automatically decay to the common state between the two commands, you would not need that.

Vulkan *kind of* has something similar to this, but not in such a direct way and not nearly as often. Vulkan's concepts of execution dependency and memory visibility cover it, but these aren't named properties of the object itself. And while there are places in the Vulkan's architecture where implicit execution and memory barriers exist, they are extremely rare. More often than not, Vulkan *requires* you to explicit perform some kind of barrier-equivalent operation to permit visibility of written data.

Answer (score 2):

No, that sounds confusing. In Vulkan resource state (layout) changes only explicitly based on your `VkImageMemoryBarrier`, `VkAttachmentDescription::finalLayout`, or `VkAttachmentReference::layout`. A resource starts its life in the layout specified in `VkImageCreateInfo::initialLayout`.

Vulkan also has a `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL` layout, which can be used for any purpose, except `vkQueuePresentKHR`, at the potential cost of performance.

Although, Vulkan can use a resource for read access in two differing layouts via subpasses. Vulkan will manage that situation automatically based on the `VkAttachmentReference::layout`s without any additional Subpass Dependency. But that is as far as Vulkan will go, and there is not any more driver magic than this.